# Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось только одно число (нужна сумма всех отрицательных чисел)

Tags: python-3.x

```
numbers = 1,-8,-4,5,12
summa = 0
for num in numbers:
    if num < 0:
        summa += num
        print(summa)
```

Comment: Можно. Достаточно понять что такое цикл.

Comment: мне в голову пришло только то, чтобы создать еще один цикл который выведет минимальное значение из всех, есть по проще вариант?

Comment: В цикле определяйте  сумму, а по его завершению выводите результат. Почитайте про циклы.

Comment: numbers = 1,-8,-4,5,12
summa = 0
result = 0
for num in numbers:
    if num < 0:
       summa += num
    result = summa
print(result)

Comment: спасибо, за наставления)

Comment: @agre откуда вы этот код взяли? Понимаете ли слово **цикл**? Понимаете ли что print(summa) у вас *внутри* цикла выполняется? Что вы думаете надо с `print(summa)` строкой сделать, чтобы она *после* цикла исполнялась? Какую роль отступы имеют в Питоне? Что произойдёт, если убрать отступ перед `print(summa)`?

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = 1,-8,-4,5,12
summa = 0
result = 0
for num in numbers:
    if num < 0:
       summa += num
    result = summa
print(result)
```

Comment: Зачем вы `result = summa` используете? Какого результата хотите достичь? Что по вашему произойдёт, если `print(summa)` после цикла добавить?

Comment: не обессудьте, я только учусь, поэтому делаю такие элементарные ошибки(

Comment: Это не страшно, все где-то начинают. Отредактируйте ваш ответ, если узнали как его можно улучшить. Словами опишите, как вы понимаете решение.